# I am trying to add comma between fields

Tags: oracle

I am trying to write a simple procedure which will concatenate three fields with comma; but the tricky part is if one of the value is missing then i dont want to see the comma in the front when there is no 1st value (,2nd field, 3rd field)
db version:oracle 11gR2 :

```
    Declare
    v_first_name  varchar2(15);
    v_last_name   varchar2(15);
    v_title       varchar2(15);
    ShowResult    varchar2 (50); 

    Begin

    v_first_name := nvl('john', null) ;
    v_last_name  := nvl('lennon',null);
    v_title      := nvl('singer',null);

    ShowResult := v_first_name ||','|| v_last_name ||','|| v_title

    I am expecting from ShowResult be like this : john,lennon, singer.

    But if any of the value v_first_name or v_last_name or v_title 
    is null then, i like to ShowResult in this way : 
        1st scenario: lennon,singer -- if v_first_name is null
        2nd scenario: john,singer   -- if v_last_name  is null
        3rd scenario: singer        -- if first name and last name r null


    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Output is '|| ShowResult);

    End;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something similar to this:

```
ShowResult := LTRIM(COALESCE(v_first_name,'') || NVL2(v_last_name,',','') || COALESCE(v_last_name,'') || NVL2(v_title,',','') || COALESCE(v_title,''),',')
```

The LTRIM() will remove the leading comma.

Version with DECODE:

```
ShowResult := LTRIM(COALESCE(v_first_name,'') || DECODE(v_last_name,null,'',',') || COALESCE(v_last_name,'') || DECODE(v_title,null,'',',') || COALESCE(v_title,''),',')
```

Comment: Thanks Lalit, but i am getting the following error:

Comment: ORA-06550: line 36, column 60:
PLS-00201: identifier 'NVL2' must be declared

Comment: It should be available to 11G http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl2.php What does your revised command look like? BTW, I put the comma in the wrong spots should be NVL2(v_last_name,',','') etc.

Comment: i figured out something interesting from googling that NVL2 () cannot be used as PL/SQL function and it is a SQL function; is there any alternative that can be used here  instead of nvl2().

Comment: Odd, I use it all the time. http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl2.php  You could also use DECODE (v_last_name,null,'',',')

Comment: ShowResult := LTRIM(COALESCE(v_first_name,'') || DECODE(v_last_name,null,'',',') || COALESCE(v_last_name,'') || DECODE(v_title,null,'',',') || COALESCE(v_title,''),',');

Comment: PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'DECODE' may be used inside a SQL statement only

Comment: Try using a select statement: SELECT LTRIM(COALESCE(v_first_name,'') || NVL2(v_last_name,',','') || COALESCE(v_last_name,'') || NVL2(v_title,',','') || COALESCE(v_title,''),',') INTO ShowResult;

Comment: SELECT LTRIM(COALESCE(v_first_name,'') || NVL2(v_last_name,',','') || COALESCE(v_last_name,'') || NVL2(v_title,',','') || COALESCE(v_title,''),',') 
INTO ShowResult
from Dual; This works but strange why Decode(), NVL2() functions did not work within PL/SQL code. I would appreciate if anybody can shed some lights here. Thanks Steve for all the help.

Comment: Thanks Steve for the info.